# Generate Credentials on Google Map API Keys for android programatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

There is any way to configure google maps api key using command line or any other way without accessing the console website? I'm  trying build and release Android APKs using command line, everything is already working fine, but every Android APK has different packageId and all of them use Google Maps. How can I automate this configuration?

```
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:C1:43:67:71:9B:62:71:AF:A1:66:6A:67:5B:75;com.example.myexample1  
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:C1:43:67:71:9B:62:71:AF:A1:66:6A:67:5B:75;com.example.myexample2
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:C1:43:67:71:9B:62:71:AF:A1:66:6A:67:5B:75;com.example.myexample3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can automate the creation of those strings (SHA and package of the app), but you can't send them and retrieve the key, you have to use the web console in the browser.
You need to create the key once, so it has a very low usefulness the script via commandline

Comment: perhaps with Selenium?

Comment: don't know selenium, but don't think so. API Console is googles and i don't think they provide APIs, so no way